Start-Process is failing to continue after devenv.com has exited
I'm launching devenv.com from a powershell script in order to perform a rebuild on my .sln project. After the build is done, I then do some other tasks such as copying files etc.
I'm calling devenv.com like this:
  Start-Process "C:\..\devenv.com" "C:\Projects\Project.sln /Rebuild Release" -Wait

This works as you'd expect in that a new console window appears, the build is performed, the process finishes and my script continues. However this only happens 9 times out of 10. Occasionally the devenv.com will finish, but powershell fails to notice and my script waits indefinitely.
Side note: the build does not contain any build errors - this problem occurs when the code can be built without error.
Is there anything else I could do in order to make this more robust?

Slightly aside, is there a reason you’re using devenv … rather than dotnet … or msbuild …? You can do automated builds with devenv but the latter two are more suited to the task as you don’t need a full Visual Studio install to use them (and I’m guessing they’d be less susceptible to intermittent weirdness like you’re seeing)…

start-process will wait for any child processes

@mclayton that is a great point...reason I'm using devenv is due to msbuild generating all kinds of build errors that both my team and I can't get to the bottom of (this is an older 4.8 project...i wish i could just use the build commands from .NET Core etc.).

@js2010 - right, so it's possible that another process was spawned?

@mclayton managed to get it working in MSBUILD in the end...it's a much better way of handling this task.
